# Does ssis sql job step by default run under context of sql job owner?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Generally TSQL job step runs under context of agent service account when the job owner belongs to sysadmin role. Unless a different user account is set in the advanced pane. However if the job owner is not a sysadmin, then job executes in context of the job owner.

I have job step that is having ssis package. `Run as` value is empty.

Assume the job owner is not a sysadmin. Then will this job step run under the context of sql job owner?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot? The `Run As` field for an SSIS job step shouldn't normally be empty, it defaults to SQL Server Agent Service Account when you create it, and remains that unless you specifically change it to a suitably configured proxy.

Comment: Only a member of sysadmin can see the agent service in the dropdown.

Comment: Correct, but for non-sysadmins, if you don't have a proxy assigned with sufficient permissions then the agent job won't run at all, it will throw an error `Non-SysAdmins have been denied permission to run DTS Execution job steps without a proxy account.`. These jobs execute DTExec outside of the SQL Server process, so for security reasons, only sysadmins or a proxy account with appropriate permissions can run these types of jobs steps, and only job owners assigned these proxies can correctly configure an agent job to run SSIS packages without sysadmin rights.

Comment: My first comment was misleading, I was assuming a sysadmin was creating the job, didn't read your question properly, sorry.

Comment: So for non syasdmin user, leaving the run as field as blank will not be able to run the job. Is there any other way (other than proxy) to prevent the `denied permission` error?

Comment: When you say proxy with sufficient permissions, what permissions are you specifically referring to?